# Proportion testing across overlapping populations in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to do a proportion test in R using a data set that reports a global cohort alongside sub-populations from East and West populations. In the sample code, 6/15 pts are EAST, 5/15 are WEST, and 4/15 are GLOBAL as it's unknown, but 15/15 should be reported as global as these are subsets of the whole.

```
set.seed(1)
dataset<-data.frame("sex"=sample(c("M","F"),15,replace=TRUE),"cohort"=sample(c("GLOBAL","EAST","WEST"),15,replace=TRUE),"grade"=sample(c(1,2,3),15,replace=TRUE))
table(dataset$sex,dataset$cohort)

    EAST GLOBAL WEST
  F    4      2    2
  M    2      2    3
 prop.table(table(dataset$sex,dataset$cohort))

     EAST    GLOBAL      WEST
 F 0.2666667 0.1333333 0.1333333
 M 0.1333333 0.1333333 0.2000000
```

How can I force it to reflect:

```
 EAST GLOBAL WEST
 F    4      8    2
 M    2      7    3
```

And then do a proportion test across these "3" populations? The same will need to be accomplished for dataset$grade, which has 3 categories.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do the proportion test you're suggesting. What is the question you're trying to answer (with the test)?

Comment: Agreed about not truly answering a question - moreso highlighting differences in baseline demographics between regions.